# Column 'sum_balance.debit' is invalid in the selected list because it's not contained in either an agregate function or the group by clause

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

```
SELECT CASE WHEN debit NOT LIKE '%[^.0-9]%'
            THEN CAST(debit as DECIMAL(9,2)) 
         ELSE NULL 
       END  AS dr,
CASE WHEN credit NOT LIKE '%[^.0-9]%'
THEN CAST(credit as DECIMAL(9,2))
ELSE NULL
END AS cr,sum_accname, sum_date, sum_description,

CAST(debit as DECIMAL(9,2)) - CAST(credit as DECIMAL(9,2))
  AS br,

SUM(CAST(debit as DECIMAL(9,2)))- SUM(CAST(credit as DECIMAL(9,2)))

FROM sum_balance
Where sum_accname = {?acc_name}
and

sum_date >= {?fromDate}
and

sum_date <= {?toDate}

group by sum_accname
```

this is my code and it's giving an error while running the report i don't know whats wrong with my code  can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: can you tell us what error you are getting from this code??

Comment: You are selecting both a sum of the debit and credits, as well as the debit and credits themselves (cr and dr). You're either going to have to add debit and credit to the group by statement or remove CR and DR from the select. You can' do a detail and a summary in the same query (not this simply anyway)

Comment: @smn_onrocks error : Column 'sum_balance.debit' is invalid in the selected list because it's not contained in either an agregate function or the group by clause